# Nginx: Configure max_fails and fail_timeout without an upstream definition

Tags: nginx

In an Nginx configuration with an upstream definition it is possible to define the parameters `max_fails` and `fail_timeout` as arguments to the `server` directive, such as:

```
upstream dynamic {
    server backend2.example.com:8080 fail_timeout=3 max_fails=3;
}
```

But in our configuration we're proxying to backends by dynamically generating the backend names based on the request, so we don't have upstream definitions:

```
proxy_pass http://${org}-http.hosted-service.svc.cluster.local:3000;
```

Is there a way how we can set the `fail_timeout` and `max_fails` globally without having to define an `upstream` for each possible value of `${org}`?

Our Nginx version is `1.13.7`